# Serialize c# DateTime to Java Time and Java Date for SAP webservice

Tags: java, c#, web-services, serialization, sap-erp

I need to upload data to SAP via a webservice, using WCF in c# 4.0 (VS2010). I have been able to connect and post data to the using the webservice successfully, however I ran into a problem with date and time.

I have an class called `MtrRdngDocERPRsltCrteReqRslt` having 2 fields called `ActualMeterReadingDate` and `ActualMeterReadingTime`. When Visual Studio generated the proxy class, it converted these objects as datetime objects, however I know they are Date and Time on the other end of the webservice (which is implemented in JAVA).

The problem is that when I pass datetime values to these fields, they are not getting serialized and are not being received on the other end.

Also note that when I serialize dates that are defined as `DateTime` by the webservice, these work perfectly.

I have also used the following code to serialize the whole object and save it locally as xml on and I have the same problem.

---

```
public void SerializeToXML(MeterReadingUploadWS2.MtrRdngDocERPRsltBulkCrteReqMsg bb, string path)
{
 System.Xml.Serialization.XmlSerializer x = new System.Xml.Serialization.XmlSerializer(bb.GetType());
            
            var serializer = new System.Xml.Serialization.XmlSerializer(bb.GetType());
            
            using (var writer = System.Xml.XmlWriter.Create(path))
            {                        
                serializer.Serialize(writer, bb);
            }
        }
```

Comment: can you show us what the bb object looks like when you serialize it locally to xml.

Comment: Difficult to say, if you don't provide the XML date format you send and the expected XML date format. Usually, SAP ERP (ECC, S/4HANA) standard webservices expect dates in format `YYYY-MM-DD` format (interpreted according to the time zone defined in the SAP system, unfortunately...), but I'm not sure which SAP software and which Webservice you are talking about.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had some troubles doing that some time ago, and I decided to work with long properties, because it's the closest generic interop way to achieve it, since c#'s DateTime and java's Date objects are different things from different languages.

Comment: so you mean you convert dates to Long?

Comment: We opted to change the webservice so it accepts date and time in agreed string formats. I think its the simplest. To avoid such a problem in the future I will make sure that only datetimes are exposed in a webservice.

Comment: Yes, converting it to long. Both approaches (using Long or String) fits your needs anyways :)

Could you mark the answer as accepted?

Comment: Serialization of dates or timestamps in XML should **always** be in [ISO-8601](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601) format, no exceptions. That is the best way to avoid ambiguities.